# Django/mod_wsgi AH01630: client denied by server configuration

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2

I am in the process of moving my Django site to Amazon EC2 and trying to configure Apache2 on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

When accessing the site I am getting an error:

```
[Sat Nov 28 05:55:54.799020 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 1657] [client 110.143.63.231:65129] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/directory/django.wsgi
```

My django.wsgi file is:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/directory/')
sys.path.append('/home/directory/directory/directory/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'  # this is your settings.py file
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/tmp'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

My 000-default.conf file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ip.add.res.s
    ServerAlias www.ip.add.res.s
    ServerAdmin example@email.com

    Alias /static/ /home/directory/static/
    <Directory "/static/">
        Options -Indexes
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /media/ /home/directory/media/
    <Directory "/media/">
        Options -Indexes
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/directory/directory/directory/django.wsgi

    <Directory "/home/directory/directory/directory">
        <Files django.py>
            Options All
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have `755`permissions on `django.wsgi` and the ip address is set in `ALLOWED_HOSTS = []`

Have been struggling on finding a solution to this.

Answer (score -2):

I think you might have to include WSGI file if you are using one. wsgi.py

Comment: It would be better if you could provide a definite answer instead of a guess, including what exactly one has to do to fix the problem in question and why. You can [edit] your answer to improve it.